# Select TOP 20 Distinct Rows in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I keep a log of User Actions in a table with a date stamp.

Each time a user goes into a project, it logs that they viewed that project and stamps the datetime.

I want to get the TOP 20 Projects that the user has last gone into.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (20) Users_Tran_ID
FROM App_UserLog
WHERE (Users_ID = 'ADMIN') AND (Users_Transaction LIKE 'Permit Viewed%')
ORDER BY App_UserLog.Users_LogDate DESC
```

The problem is, I don't want the Users_LogDate in my output, as I need UNIQUE Users_Tran_ID.

When I remove the Users_LogDate from the SELECT I get the following error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Here is the basic select and result set I get.  I just want the distinct Users_Tran_ID and only the TOP 20.

```
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 17:35:04.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 17:29:09.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2006-0043  2013-08-29 17:29:05.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 17:28:49.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2008-0167  2013-08-29 17:17:13.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2006-0043  2013-08-29 17:17:08.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 17:16:55.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 17:16:45.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 17:16:38.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 17:16:32.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 11:39:59.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 11:22:05.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 11:22:03.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:23:17.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:21:58.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:20:41.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:20:37.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 10:18:01.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 10:17:58.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:17:54.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:01:50.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2011-0012  2013-08-29 10:01:48.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 09:56:32.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 09:53:31.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   B2007-0478  2013-08-29 09:53:27.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-15 12:51:09.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-15 12:51:07.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   BLD2012-0094    2013-08-13 12:01:39.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:34.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:28.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:24.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:21.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:13.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:09.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2013-0047    2013-08-05 10:40:07.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-05 10:37:55.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-05 10:37:50.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-05 10:37:46.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-05 10:37:40.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-05 10:37:33.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0141    2013-08-05 10:37:31.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   BLD2012-0919    2013-08-05 10:27:21.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   BLD2012-0919    2013-08-05 10:27:17.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0119    2013-08-05 10:26:51.000
ADMIN   Permit Viewed   ENG2012-0119    2013-08-05 10:26:48.000
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Is Transaction ID per project? I don't see anything identifying a project in your query?

Comment: The Users_Tran_ID contains the PROJECT number I need.  My top line I will edit, I really only need Users_Tran_ID in my final result.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `group by` rather than `distinct`:

```
SELECT TOP (20) Users_Tran_ID
FROM App_UserLog
WHERE (Users_ID = 'ADMIN') AND (Users_Transaction LIKE 'Permit Viewed%')
GROUP BY Users_Tran_ID
ORDER BY max(App_UserLog.Users_LogDate) DESC;
```

With aggregation, you can then specify that you want to order by the most recent logdate.  Voila, that should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Users_ID, Users_Transaction, Users_Tran_ID
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (20) Users_ID, Users_Transaction, Users_Tran_ID, Users_LogDate
    FROM App_UserLog
    WHERE (Users_ID = 'ADMIN') AND (Users_Transaction LIKE 'Permit Viewed%')
    ORDER BY App_UserLog.Users_LogDate DESC
) as a
```

Comment: Almost Had it, but thanks... that worked:

SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 Users_Tran_ID FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT TOP (20) Users_ID, Users_Transaction, Users_Tran_ID, Users_LogDate FROM App_UserLog WHERE (Users_ID = 'ADMIN') AND (Users_Transaction LIKE 'Permit Viewed%') ORDER BY App_UserLog.Users_LogDate DESC ) t

Comment: @BitcoSoftware And what is different in the results from your expectation?

Comment: I edited my answer appending `as a` to name the subquery. Now using @FabienTheSolution 's Fiddle, to me the result seems ok. You did not state what is the difference between the result produced by this proposal and the result you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this :

```
SELECT TOP 20 Users_ID, 
              Users_Transaction, 
              Users_Tran_ID 
         FROM ( SELECT Users_ID, 
                       Users_Transaction, 
                       Users_Tran_ID, 
                       max(Users_LogDate) as MaxUsers_LogDate
                  FROM App_UserLog
                 WHERE (Users_ID = 'ADMIN') AND 
                       (Users_Transaction LIKE 'Permit Viewed%')
              GROUP BY Users_ID, Users_Transaction, Users_Tran_ID
             ) AS TopTransactions
ORDER BY MaxUsers_LogDate DESC
```

See [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8e3eb/18/0)